# How to get custom error on required field with default browser submit event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When submit `event` performed it usually sees which required field is not filled and then popover the first field of required first.

```
<div class="row">
 <form>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="detailsInput">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstname" required data-maxlength="20" placeholder="First Name" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const nameInput = document.querySelector('#firstName');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  if (!nameInput.checkValidity()) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
  nameInput.setCustomValidity('Please enter your name'); // Set custom error 
  message
 }
});
```

I'm currently triggering error which reflects all the fields but not the first `required` one.

EDIT:
Need custom error message on popover in default event browser behavior.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the issue is currently?

Comment: I guess you're trying to customize the required error message?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get custom error message from browser default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input[name="firstname"]');

input.addEventListener('invalid', function(event) {
  if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Please tell us your lovely name.');
  }
})

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  event.target.setCustomValidity('');
})
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Reference: https://angelika.me/2020/02/01/custom-error-messages-for-html5-form-validation/